# Is there a recognised soteriology that combines selective election for some and general election for everyone else?

Tags: soteriology, reformed-theology, free-will, arminianism, unconditional-election

Are there any Christian groups or denominations that hold a belief in selective election to salvation, in that some individuals are specifically and irresistibly called (Noah, Moses, 12 desciples, Paul etc.) for a particular purpose, but that most people are generally called "resistibly" and can accept or reject the gospel of their own free will? Essentially, free will exists allowing people to resist God's grace if they choose, except a certain few which God does not give a choice.

As this came up in conversation, I believe the other party was trying to reconcile differences between Calvinist and Arminian doctrines on salvation. I'm trying to determine if there are any relatively mainstream Christian groups or denominations that hold this sort of belief.

Comment: If you are talking about a selective election to salvation (as opposed to some specific ministry or task), it sounds like a fairly novel doctrine; but given there are thousands of denominations, it's pretty hard to prove a negative.  Do you have any reason to think there might be?

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. It's a fairly straightforward question and because of the difficulty of proving a negative I specifically am asking for evidence of a positive. The topic came up in conversation and I am wondering if there are such beliefs held by any denominations or groups.

Comment: I didn't downvote myself, but your question is not exactly clear (especially in view of the fact that the tags you've chosen are actually inappropriate) and doesn't seem to be useful.  They are both valid criteria for downvoting.

Comment: I'll edit the question to be more clear. As for usefulness, it's useful to me, I'm here to get an academic answer to a question about Christianity.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what topics work here for questions, please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines). These should help you to refine your questions so that the regulars here aren't inclined to downvote them for being unclear or off-topic.

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad.  Given the absence of any evidence that there are many such soteriologies, I don't see how the "too broad" close reason is relevant.  "Too broad" means that "good answers would be too long for this format," not "finding an answer will be tough."

Comment: I also don't think it's too broad. We have other questions that remain open here asking if there are denominations that believe particular doctrines.

Comment: There is an attempt to solve both Calvinist and Arminian doctrines on salvation, that I know of,  but not in the way of selective election.

Comment: I think it is useful to note, that although God has "predestined" some for salvation and some for destruction (example: Pharaoh and Moses), does not mean there is no free will on the side of these parties. God, being all-knowing, knows beforehand whom will accept Him, and whom will reject Him. This does not infringe on the free will of man. It is simply a sign of an all-powerful, all-knowing God.

Answer (score 1):

Although I honestly do not know too much about Roman Catholicism, it would seem they believe in "selective election" or predestined salvation.

**This is an excerpt from Wikipedia: Predestination**

> Roman Catholicism
>
> Roman Catholicism teaches the doctrine of predestination, while
>   rejecting the classical Calvinist view known as "double
>   predestination." **This means that while it is held that those whom
>   God has elected to eternal life will infallibly attain it, and are
>   therefore said to be predestined to salvation by God**, those who
>   perish are not predestined to damnation. But Catholicism has been
>   generally discouraging to human attempts to guess or predict the
>   Divine Will.
>
> The Catholic Encyclopedia entry on Predestination says:
>
> God, owing to His infallible prescience of the future, has appointed
>   and ordained from eternity all events occurring in time, especially
>   those that directly proceed from, or at least are influenced by, man's
>   free will.

I hope this helps!